# How to sort Culture Specific DataTime Column in a datatable(jquery) which has empty columns too

Tags: jquery, sorting, model-view-controller, datatable

I am working on mvc and using datatable which has a column of type datetime. This column has few blank( empty) cells too. This I am achiving by using a string property to fill the column instead of datetime property. Also, the date should be **culture-specific**

html code:

```html
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.XYZ)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.AccountName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.AccountId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.LastLoginDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
                    {
                        <text>@item.sLastLoginDate</text>
                    }
                    else
                    {
      //this is where customCulture will get its value from :  
                        //CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("some culture");
                  
                        <text>@item.LastLoginDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", customCulture)</text>  
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

C# code for Model:

```html
for(some iterations)  
{
 DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

 XYZEntity objXYZEntity = new XYZEntity();
 if (!row["sAccounts"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
  objXYZEntity.AccountName = Convert.ToString(row["sAccounts"]);
 if (!row["lAccountID"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
  objXYZEntity.AccountId = Convert.ToString(row["lAccountID"]);
 if (!row["dLastLoginTime"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
  objXYZEntity.LastLoginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dLastLoginTime"]);
 objXYZEntity.sLastLoginDate = string.Empty; //using string property in case database cell is empty
    
 lstXYZEntity.Add(objXYZEntity);
}
return lstXYZEntity;
```

I have taken  a string property "sLastLoginDate" and a datetime property "LastLoginDate". when the cell in database is empty, i am using "sLastLoginDate" instead of the datetime property "LastLoginDate".
But with all this implementation, I am not able to proprly sort this datetime column.